# Restrict access to apache 2.4 directory but allow certain files

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2.4

I have an apache 2.4 server which is hosting 2 applications. One of which is freely accessible to the internet and the other is restricted to certain IPs. So within my /etc/apache2.conf file I have the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/other/>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require ip [ip]
</Directory>
```

This works fine and I get a 403 forbidden when trying to access any page being served from /var/other unless im on the right IP. However, I would now like to make certain pages within the /var/other/ directory freely accessible without the IP restriction. I have tried various combinations such as the following which has a nested <Files> tag to grant all access to a specific file but doesnt seem to work.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/other/>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require ip [ip]
   <Files "/var/other/page.php">
      Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

Ive tried putting the <Files> tag before the "Require ip [ip]" as well as before and after the <Directory> tag but also dont seem to work. Does anyone know if this is possible and how I would go about implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have the directory, just the filename, in the Files section:

```
   <Files "page.php">
```